# How do I get .sub/.srt files to be displayed in the Video file explorer? (XBMC)

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I like being able to see the `.srt`/`.sub` files in my file explorer as I'm browsing my videos, just to be able to know if the video file has subtitle files before I play it.

After looking at this [wiki page on the advancedsettings.xml file](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=advancedsettings.xml), I've tried adding an `advancedsettings.xml` file under `~/.xbmc/userdata/` with the following, thinking that XBMC would consider it a video file and, therefore, display it in the file explorer:

```
<advancedsettings>
  <videoextensions>
    <add>.sub</add>
    <add>.srt</add>
  </videoextensions>
</advancedsettings>
```

But that didn't seem to work, and I'm out of ideas/googlefu. Anyone have an idea how I might be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely you'll manage to display subtitles in the list, because they are not "playable" files and XBMC people would not like their support to be overflown with questions like "why playback does not start when I click subtitle file?" and alike.

on the other hand, there are multiple file formats (.mkv?) that support multiple subtitle channels embedded in, you won't be able to display subtitles for these as well.

all in all, it's basically not worth the trouble =)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's not an answer to your question but something that could help you with subtitles (I don't have enough points to just add a comment). If you don't know about it, please take a look at the [XBMC Subtitles](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on%3aXBMC_Subtitles) add-on. It can help you download subtitles directly from the video from various providers.

Comment: Yup, I have that installed already, thanks. I've even got the add-on script mapped to a keybinding so I don't have to use the mouse to click on the icon when I've just started my show. My question is more out of curiosity, and in general I'd just like to know how to be able to have "other" files be displayed in the file explorer other than the ones with the "regular" video/music extensions.